# I want to change the highlight field in elasticsearch to snippet(S). I am using sense(kibana) to display the result

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

This is my query:

```
GET index6april/_search
{
  "fields": ["T","U", "UD", "UE"],
"query":{
    "match_phrase": {
      "newContent": "white"
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "newContent" : {"fragment_size" : 150, "number_of_fragments" : 3}
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this query is:

```
{
  "took": 24,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0.08275573,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/",
        "_score": 0.08275573,
        "fields": {
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Enterprise Search and Big Data Experts"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ],
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "-Commerce Media & Publishing Government Fraud Detection Recruiting Log Analytics Customers Representative Customers Case Studies Resources Blog <em>White</em> Papers",
            " Careers Federal Contract Vehicles Customer Support Contact Us Customer Success Story Adecco Recruits with Search & Big Data Featured <em>White</em> Paper Smart",
            " Evaluation Enterprise Search <em>White</em> Papers Search Quality Analysis Search & Big Data Managed Services Microsoft Search Services SharePoint 2013 Search Services"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/support",
        "_score": 0.08108373,
        "fields": {
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/support"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Search Technologies"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/support"
          ],
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/support"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "-Commerce Media & Publishing Government Fraud Detection Recruiting Log Analytics Customers Representative Customers Case Studies Resources Blog <em>White</em> Papers",
            " Search Engines Is A Lot of Hard Work Other Resources Enterprise Search Case Studies Statistical Relevancy Evaluation Enterprise Search <em>White</em> Papers"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Account/Login/",
        "_score": 0.07644647,
        "fields": {
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Account/Login/"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Log in"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Account/Login/"
          ],
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Account/Login/"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "-Commerce Media & Publishing Government Fraud Detection Recruiting Log Analytics Customers Representative Customers Case Studies Resources Blog <em>White</em> Papers"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/terms",
        "_score": 0.04729884,
        "fields": {
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/terms"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Terms of Use"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/terms"
          ],
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/terms"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "-Commerce Media & Publishing Government Fraud Detection Recruiting Log Analytics Customers Representative Customers Case Studies Resources Blog <em>White</em> Papers",
            " Relevancy Evaluation Enterprise Search <em>White</em> Papers Search Quality Analysis Search & Big Data Managed Services Microsoft Search Services SharePoint 2013"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/modernizr?v=7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1",
        "_score": 0.038223237,
        "fields": {
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/modernizr?v=7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1"
          ],
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/modernizr?v=7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/modernizr?v=7-yR01kdRVQ7W1RQzMBVKYLDhCt0itEATWHixfzE8Os1"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "=function(){var n=\"background-image:\",t=\"gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#9f9),to(<em>white</em>));\",i=\"linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, <em>white</em>);\";return",
            ",from(#9f9),to(<em>white</em>));\",i=\"linear-gradient(left top,#9f9, <em>white</em>);\";return a((n+\"-webkit- \".split(\" \").join(t+n)+y.join(i+n)).slice(0,-n.length)),v"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Content/css/customcss?v=ByvyFKgvAaWSEqvyecWIUDY7OhTiu-K7fyOIXe3rZpI1",
        "_score": 0.027027909,
        "fields": {
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Content/css/customcss?v=ByvyFKgvAaWSEqvyecWIUDY7OhTiu-K7fyOIXe3rZpI1"
          ],
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Content/css/customcss?v=ByvyFKgvAaWSEqvyecWIUDY7OhTiu-K7fyOIXe3rZpI1"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/Content/css/customcss?v=ByvyFKgvAaWSEqvyecWIUDY7OhTiu-K7fyOIXe3rZpI1"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            ":12px}.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{color:#dadada}.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{background-color:#eee}.btn{<em>white</em>-space:normal}.homepage_box_small div{min",
            " solid #ccc;border-radius:5px;line-height:.8em;padding:2px 8px 2px 8px!important;text-decoration:none;<em>white</em>-space:nowrap;display:inline-block}.category"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/js?v=SR_15IYr6MhqwbGxnaF13IhSSVER392Fy422ucY4GvM1",
        "_score": 0.016722666,
        "fields": {
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/js?v=SR_15IYr6MhqwbGxnaF13IhSSVER392Fy422ucY4GvM1"
          ],
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/js?v=SR_15IYr6MhqwbGxnaF13IhSSVER392Fy422ucY4GvM1"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/bundles/js?v=SR_15IYr6MhqwbGxnaF13IhSSVER392Fy422ucY4GvM1"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "newContent": [
            "\").html(\"The <em>white</em> paper download link has been emailed to you at \"+r+\". <br />Please check your junk mail if you have a strong email filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am getting a highlight field in the output which is highlighting few contents from the newcontent. I want to have highlight field inside the snippet . I want my output to look like this:

```
{
  "took": 24,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0.08275573,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index6april",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/",
        "_score": 0.08275573,
        "fields": {
          "U": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Enterprise Search and Big Data Experts"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ],
          "UE": [
            "http://www.searchtechnologies.com/"
          ]
        },
        "S": {
          "newContent": [
            "-Commerce Media & Publishing Government Fraud Detection Recruiting Log Analytics Customers Representative Customers Case Studies Resources Blog <em>White</em> Papers",
            " Careers Federal Contract Vehicles Customer Support Contact Us Customer Success Story Adecco Recruits with Search & Big Data Featured <em>White</em> Paper Smart",
            " Evaluation Enterprise Search <em>White</em> Papers Search Quality Analysis Search & Big Data Managed Services Microsoft Search Services SharePoint 2013 Search Services"
          ]
        }
      },
...................
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that currently (`Elasticsearch` 2.3) there is such an option.

Comment: True. I didn't find any solution for this. Thanks.